# Why does List.reversed() work in LeetCode's Java environment but not in standard Java?

Tags: java, list, reverse, java-17

I recently encountered a piece of Java code on **LeetCode** that uses a `reversed()` method directly on a `List<Integer>` object, like so:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
System.out.println(l.reversed());  // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

To my knowledge, and according to the Java 17 API documentation, the `List` interface does not have a `reversed()` method.

However, this code compiles and runs successfully within the LeetCode environment. This behavior has left me puzzled because, in a standard Java environment (like IntelliJ IDEA with JDK 17), this code results in a compilation error, as expected.

I am curious if anyone can explain why this code works on LeetCode. Are there any common extensions or custom libraries that LeetCode might use to enable such syntax in their Java environment?

#### My Question:

1. Why does the `reversed()` method work on a `List` object in LeetCode's Java environment?
2. How can one implement to enable this `.reversed()` functionality in a standard Java environment?

Comment: Easy: [`List.reversed()` got added in Java 21](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) so of course it won't work in Java 17 :) - There are plenty alternatives, from using `Collections.reverse()` for in-place reversal over using a list iterator and traversing backwards to using a library such as Apache Commons or Google Guava which have their own reverse iterators.

Comment: You seem to think "standard Java" means Java 17? Java 21 is the latest long-term supported version, which was released 6 months ago, and Java 22 has just been released.